# TCP port 80 not shown in listening list after adding Inbound and outbound policies on Azure cloud Machine

Tags: azure, tcp, port

I logged in into cloud machine and added the inbound and outbound rules for TCP port 80 and 443.

After that when i check from the command prompt netstat -an command. The TCP port 80 and 443 was not listed.

Can any one help me in resolving this issue.

Regards
Mohd Shoeb

Comment: We should run application listen on port 443 and 80, then we can use `netstat -an` to list them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that when i check from the command prompt netstat -an command.
>   The TCP port 80 and 443 was not listed.

According to your description, we should run some application, like IIS or apache to **listen on** port 80 or 443, after the application **running** correct, we can use `netstat -an` to list them.

Comment: Jason now the port 80 is used by IIS. i am installing an application called DLP triton server which communicates over 80 and 443 can this application use this ports.

Comment: @MohdShoeb By default, one port work for one application, if you want to use port 80 and 443 for  DLP triton, I think we should change IIS port settings.

Comment: @MohdShoeb Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Ye yes the answer was helpful